# Changing contents of array using outside variable

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, vector

I would like to know if its possible to change the value of multiple arrays by changing the variable I used to fill them.

Here is an example:

```
String firstArg = "?a";
String secondArg = "?b";

String[] action = { "jump", firstArg, secondArg }
String[] action2 = { "run", secondArg, firstArg }
```

The vectors would be like these for the first moment:

```
Action { "jump", "?a", "?b" }

Action { "run", "?b", "?a" }
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
firstArg = "k";
```

And now my vectors would be like these:

```
Action { "jump", "k", "?b" }

Action { "run", "?b", "k" }
```

Is this possible ? I tried but the values of vectors didn't changed, I know that Java is not C, and it does not work like pointers..

But I guess that there might be a way to do this.. how ?

Thanks a lot in advance ;)

Comment: Welcome to Java, the world where everything has to be a reference! And there is NO WAY to use POINTERS, which could solve your problem in no-time.

Comment: So how can I solve this one ?

Comment: In Java a `String` is immutable. You could write a mutable `String` wrapper and then do something like `firstArg.setVal("k")`.

Comment: You can introduce objects to hold references to these strings. Your vector could then contain references to those objects, which would in turn allow you to switch the values around as necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Java syntax for achieving what you want -- changing the object referred to by one variable changes the object referred to by other variables.

You can simulate this by creating and using your own object to refer to the string in question.

```
public class StringHolder {
   private String myString;
   public StringHolder(String string) {
      myString = string;
   }
   public void setString(String string) {
      myString = string;
   }
   public String getString() {
      return myString;
   }
}
```

Then you can have arrays of `StringHolder` objects.

```
StringHolder firstArg = new StringHolder("?a");
StringHolder secondArg = new StringHolder("?b");

StringHolder[] action = { new StringHolder("jump"), firstArg, secondArg }
StringHolder[] action2 = { new StringHolder("run"), secondArg, firstArg }

firstArg.setString("k");
```

You would have to call `getString()` to get the string out again, but because `firstArg` would be the same object in `action` and in `action2`, modifying it would achieve your result.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I program in JAVA for a few years and this didn't came to my mind, easy solution, I am so stupid. Thanks alot mate! Appreciated ;)